# How to use class SoapClient in Laravel's Job?

Tags: php, laravel, soap-client, jobs

I have an WebApp using Laravel Framework (5.7).

On my Macbook, I installed:

> 1. Php 7.2.1
> 2. Composer 1.7.2
> 3. XAMPP 4.4.1

When I run: `$ php artisan queue:work`

Every things are fine! My Job working perfect (It call to APIs on ASP.NET services - asmx)

BUT!!!

When I deploy my WebApp on Linux Server..., it doesn't work!!!

In `failed_jobs` table I see this message: `Class 'SoapClient' not found`. 
And when I call by WebBrowser (Ex: `http://my_server_linux_ip/dosomething`, It work!)

I really turn on `soap` extension in `php.ini`

My Linux Server is installed:

> 1. Php 7.2.13
> 2. Composer 1.7.2
> 3. Apache2

My `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        ....
}
```

Php-Soap:

```
$ apt-cache search php | grep -i soap
libnusoap-php - SOAP toolkit for PHP
php7.0-soap - SOAP module for PHP
python-pysimplesoap - simple and lightweight SOAP Library (Python 2)
python3-pysimplesoap - simple and lightweight SOAP Library (Python 3)
php-soap - SOAP module for PHP [default]
php5.6-soap - SOAP module for PHP
php5.6-soap-dbgsym - debug symbols for php5.6-soap
php7.0-soap-dbgsym - debug symbols for php7.0-soap
php7.1-soap - SOAP module for PHP
php7.1-soap-dbgsym - debug symbols for php7.1-soap
php7.2-soap - SOAP module for PHP
php7.2-soap-dbgsym - debug symbols for php7.2-soap
php7.3-soap - SOAP module for PHP
php7.3-soap-dbgsym - debug symbols for php7.3-soap
```

I don't know why!

Help me! Thanks!

Comment: Most likely you need to install php7-soap.

Comment: I really installed php7.2 soap

Comment: Oh, php-cli. 
`php --ini
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini`

Open it (20-soap.ini) and remove `;` on line `;extension=soap.so`. Restart Apache, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you run `php -m` on your server? do you see `SoapClient enabled` there?

if yes, then try to run `composer dump-autoload -o` (after you make sure that your vendor folder contains the right package) on your server.

Comment: I know the reason! When I run through Browser, Php map to APACHE config (`etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini`). But when Job runs, it isn’t through APACHE, it runs through CLI. So PHP should be mapped to `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini`. So I open that file and add `extension=soap.so`, It work!